# AWS ELB (Network Load Balancer) Proxy Protocol with Nginx

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx

I'm using a NLB with an nginx stream that has upstreams to a node.js app, this is what I have for the nginx config:

```
stream {
        upstream https_stream {
          hash $remote_addr;
          server 127.0.0.1:8000;
          server 127.0.0.1:8001;
        }
        server {
          listen 443 proxy_protocol;
          proxy_pass https_stream;
        }
}
```

I'm trying to get the client ip in my node applications and from what I understand if I enable Proxy Protocol v2 from the Target Group this could work.  I've done this and https is working and being terminated from the node app (which is what I want), however the ip is `::ffff:127.0.0.1`.  I'm using express and have `app.set('trust proxy', true)`.  I believe what I need to do is in nginx use `$proxy_protocol_addr` to pass to `X-Forwarded-For`, however I'm not sure how to do that or if I'm on the right path.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason you terminated the HTTPS on the NodeJS App? I think since the HTTPS is not terminated on NGINX, you may not be able to add the client ip as a header to the encrypted body when using nginx as a proxy. Instead if you terminate the https on nginx, and reverse proxy via NGINX, you could set trust proxy and pass a X-Forwarded-For . (That is how we have done it)

Comment: Yeah needs to be done in the app, supports dynamic domains and ssl issuance.